# Different numColumns for different parts of Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I would like to render a React Native Flatlist where the first two elements span the entire width of the screen while all consecutive elements span half the screen. Like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with one Flatlist? If not, what is the best way to do something like this? Preferably without a Scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first redesign your data structure. Then you can do it with View and defined width?

```
const data = [
{
   fields: 'SingleColumn',
}, 
{
   fields: ['First Column','Second Column']
}

]

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    
     return <View>
            { somecondition ? <View>
                   <View style={{ width: '50% }}>
            ...content...
                    </View>
            <View style={{ width: '50%' }}>
             ...second column
            </View> : <View style={{ width: '100%'}}>
                          ..single column content
                      </View>
           </View>
         }
}
```

Comment: This would work visually but loses the performance benefits of using FlatList on large datasets

Comment: @Nabil Freeman agree. What to you, roughly, would be regarded as a large dataset? Do you have experience on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple column numbers in one FlatList but you could achieve what you want by extracting out the first two elements from your data structure and rendering them as a header using the [ListHeaderComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent) property on FlatList. Then you can render the rest of your array as a regular FlatList.

Comment: Whoah I have no idea how I missed this. Honestly had no idea there was a ListHeader Component. This is awesome thanks!